# What happens when power goes off suddenly?

Tags: power-supply, ubuntu, server

I have a pi 4. While running it, the electricity was gone.After electricity was back, it was working perfectly.

What can happen if this sort of power cut occurs multiple times?

Comment: It's a bit like crossing the street on a red light. Most of the time, nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What can happen if this sort pf power cut occurs" most of the time **NOTHING**.

If the Pi is updating the SD Card it may become corrupted.

The usual procedure by most of the experienced PI users if this happens is to restore from your backup.

After 7 years and 8 Pi I have never suffered corruption in a power outage,

HOWEVER I **ALWAYS** backup before doing an upgrade - which is risky even with no power problems.